# Вопрос по ID в HTML и JS

Tags: javascript, html

Имеем несколько id: icon_1, icon_2, icon_3. Хочется в скрипте написать "универсальный" id, для которого будут происходить к-л действия, чтобы получилось что-то типа icon_[i].
Есть ли такие возможности у JS?

Чтобы не писать каждый раз для каждого id к-л действия в скрипте:

```
document.getElementById("icon_1").classList.remove("nav-icon--active");

document.getElementById("icon_2").classList.remove("nav-icon--active");
```

Comment: добавь всем элементам один класс...  тот самы универсальный ID и есть класс... ID может быть один единственный и уникальный

Comment: посмотри тут пример наглядный...  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734884/Как-сменить-backgorund-color-в-ячейках-таблицы-при-нажатии

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="icon_"]');` - вернет все елементы, у которых `id` начинается на `icon_`, далее делайте с ними все что угодна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
for(var i = 1; i<idLength; ++i){
   document.getElementById("icon_"+i).classList.remove("nav-icon--active");
}
```

Но это обычно не лучший способ, посмотрите, может можно задать этим элемнтам один class и уже манипулировать ими?

Comment: пропустил точку idLength

Comment: не, id это не массив, а просто абстрактная переменная idLength с количеством id данного типа

Comment: а количество как он должен просчитать? впервые вижу такую конструкцию, объясни поподробней, будь другом?

Comment: Ну в том то и дело, что мы не знаем сколько этих id, их нужно присвоить в другом месте, из текста задачи просто непонятно, по какому принципу определять их количество, поэтому idLength это просто переменная, которая задаётся где-то не в этом участке кода

Comment: Все, понял о чем ты...  Благодарю, я сразу не сообразил...

Answer (score 0):

Как пример, можно использовать цикл:

```
let count = document.getElementByClassName('nav-icon--active').length; //получаем количество элементов, которые вы используете по классу.
for (let i = 1; i<=count; i++)
{
     document.getElementById('icon_' + i).classList.remove('nav-icon--active'); //подставляем вместо цифры i, можно подставлять любое число.
}
```

Советую вам ознакомиться с [преобразованием примитивов](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion).